# Automatically add comma to end of JavaScript objects in VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I would show a gif of the problem if I could, but I couldn't see an immediately easy way to do it.

When I'm editing a JavaScript object in VSCode, specifically, the `styles` object in React component that uses [react-jss](https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss), I have this issue:

Starting state:

```
const styles = {
   root: {}, 

   somethingElse: {}, 
}
```

Place cursor:

```
const styles = {
   root: {}, 
   |
   somethingElse: {}, 
}
```

Start new variable, which is an object:

```
const styles = {
   root: {}, 
   helloWord: {|
   somethingElse: {}, 
}
```

Press enter:

```
const styles = {
   root: {}, 
   helloWord: {
    |
   } //Missing comma!
   somethingElse: {}, 
}
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `I would show a gif of the problem if I could` to be honest, I much prefer your current presentation. It's simple and I can look at each "frame" as much as I want before moving on. Also, it doesn't rely on external data.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this. you could write [a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).